# Get project V2 item ID using its name

Tags: github-actions

I'm trying to create a workflow on my GitHub project V2 (not classic) and I need to get the ID of a specific item using its name. I tried this code, but it doesn't work:

```
name: Get Card ID on Issue Close

on:
  issues:
    types:
      - closed

jobs:
  getCardId:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Fetch Card ID
        id: fetchCardId
        run: |
          QUERY='query {
            repository(owner: "owner-name", name: "repo-name") {
              project(number: 2) {
                item: itemByName(name: "Play music throw the AUX jack") {
                  id
                }
              }
            }
          }'
          PAYLOAD=$(echo "$QUERY" | jq -c .)
          ITEM_ID=$(curl -s -H "Authorization: bearer ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" -X POST -d "$PAYLOAD" https://api.github.com/graphql | jq -r '.data.repository.project.item.id')
          echo "::set-output name=item_id::$ITEM_ID"

      - name: Print Card Name and ID
        run: |
          CARD_NAME="Play music throw the AUX jack"
          CARD_ID="${{ needs.fetchCardId.outputs.item_id }}"
          echo "Card name: $CARD_NAME --> ID: $CARD_ID"
```

And because it's a V2 project, I can't use the REST API. If anyone has an idea to solve this problem, it would be awesome.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `QUERY` doesn't have JSON. That looks like GraphQL query. But, you're using `jq` on it. That must be failing.

Comment: See https://github.com/octokit/graphql-action.